# ffmpeg decoding ogg adds samples in the end, resulting in a too long output

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, ogg, encoder, vorbis

When decoding a ogg file with ffmpeg, the output raw audio includes a "tail" in the end. Although ffprobe reports the correct duration in both samples and seconds, about 8ms is added to the end of the decoded file.

This sounds to me like an encoder delay thing, and I have experience with this in mp3 (LAME tag) and m4a (ITUNSMB tag), but not with ogg.

When I open the same ogg file in audacity, the file is decoded correctly, without the "tail" (and audacity is using ffmpeg..). So there seems to be enough information in the file to decode it correctly.

I'm considering parsing ffprobe and truncating to `duration_ts` number of frames, but if there is some build flag for ffmpeg I would rather this be handled by the decoder...

Here is an image of the same file first decoded by ffmpeg and imported as raw (with the tail), and then opened and decoded by audacity (without the tail):

[image: Audacity Screenshot]

Any clues?

Here is full ffmpeg output:

```
PS D:\audio-test> .\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f ogg -i sine-scale.ogg -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -acodec pcm_s16le sinescale-s16le
ffmpeg version N-87327-g18821e3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 75.100 / 55. 75.100
  libavcodec     57.106.101 / 57.106.101
  libavformat    57. 82.100 / 57. 82.100
  libavdevice    57.  8.101 / 57.  8.101
  libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, ogg, from 'sine-scale.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 23 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 120 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vorbis (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, s16le, to 'sinescale-s16le':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.106.101 pcm_s16le
size=     431kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 705.6kbits/s speed= 357x
video:0kB audio:431kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

Comment: Try with the libvorbis decoder: `ffmpeg.exe -c:a libvorbis -i sine-scale.ogg -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 sinescale-s16le`